# What is the optimal structure in PhpStorm for multiple applications that share a global codebase?

Tags: php, phpstorm, intellisense

I have an interesting project structure to work with that works something like follows:

```
root/
* globals/
*   * /services
*   * /libraries
* sites/
*   * /site1
*   * /site2
*   * /site3
*   * /site4
```

Each of these sites is a different application. However, each shares this global folder via symlinks. So site1 has directly under it a services and libraries folder.

What is the best way to establish this in PhpStorm so that my intellisense knows what the hell I'm talking about when I say DOCUMENT_ROOT/services or DOCUMENT_ROOT/libraries?

So it is absolutely clear, the globals folder is modified constantly. It would be very efficient to be able to Shift+F12 or CTRL+B my way to that file in globals so I can modify it, but I can't when PhpStorm doesn't see it, or confuses it with the symlink folders.

Comment: If you talking about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` then it's resolved to project root. Your textual description is a bit confusing/unclear (for me, at least) .. so it would be good to see actual screenshot of your Project View panel with folders structure there. But I would do my project structure this way: separate project for each site (e.g. `site1` is a project root for "Project 1"). Since you have symlinks there, your stuff from `globals/*` will be accessible there. If not -- they can be added separately as Additional Content Roots via Settings/Preferences.